Estimated marginal trends after regression of isometric log ratio transformed compositional data
I have longitudinal compositional data with four base response variables. I would like to compare the slopes of groups across time, but not for the ilr-transformed composition. I wish to compare the effects by groups over time on the original variables. Can this be done?

It sounds like you have compositional data on individuals over time, such that $a_{it} + b_{it} + c_{it} + d_{it} = 1$ at each $t$. These individuals belong to groups, and you want to confirm if these groups have different growth rates in these four outcomes?

That is exactly what I wish to do. Were it not compositional data, I'd know what do to.

I would use fmlogit or dirifit (as in this example) with a set of group dummies, a continuous time variable, and group x time interactions. Other controls could be added as well. You can then calculate the marginal effect of time for each group, and conduct your hypothesis tests that they are all equal.
You could also use a set of dummies instead if that flexibility makes more sense and you have enough data to estimate the extra parameters.
The standard errors must be clustered by unit to reflect the longitudinal structure.
Since this is probably a large number of hypotheses, especially with time dummies, some sort of multiple-testing correction would be appropriate.

My data is not compositions of counts but of continuous measurements.

And why is that a problem?

I presumed that both answers were pertinent, and one answer stated "You have to model counts rather than proportions, as a proportion based on 1000 observations is much more reliable than one based on 10 observations."

That does not apply to your situation.
